# fetch returning html markup

Tags: javascript, fetch

I was trying to use fetch to get some data back from a text file. However, instead, this is what i'm getting back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/><meta name="note" content="environment=development"/><script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script></head><body><div id="___gatsby"></div><script src="/commons.js"></script></body></html>
```

**data.txt** does not even contain that markup but this is what i'm getting back.

This is the fetch section of my work. Could anyone help me with that.

```
     fetch('data.txt',{mode: 'no-cors'})
     .then(response => {
         if (!response.ok) {
             throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
         }
         return response.text();
     })
     .then(function(data){
         console.log(data);
     })
```

**data.txt** just contain some random text by the way.

Comment: Is this running on the client or server and you're just trying to get the content of data.txt locally?  It look like you're trying to get the content of the file from the client side.  Is your server setup to response and serve static content?  Also you need to specify the route url to your server and resource you want to retrieve.

Comment: This is from a static site. There is no server or backend. That fetching is hardcoded into one of the components of the site.